# Goal event not showing data correctly in GA and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am tracking PDF download as goal event in GA and GTM. I have created a TAG in GTM which works when a PDF is downloaded from the website. This action is properly tracked in GA in events and I  can see the data in the event report.

Goals set up is working correctly but there is data discrepancy 
I have downloaded PDF 10 times but when I see the data in the report for Goals it shows that PDF is downloaded only 1 time rather showing 10
Can anybody suggest why there is difference in the data it is already more than 24 hrs time that I have created goal in GA
Thanks in advance

Comment: Goals are counted only once per session - so if you downloaded the pdf multiple times within a session you have several events, but only one goal conversion. Could that be it ?

Comment: Thanks Eike for the info. Just wanted to know if there is any  option/method available were I can track exactly no. of downloads using Goal event methodology.

Comment: No. You can create a custom metric for downloads or simply count the number of events, but goals are one conversion per session and thus do not reflect the actual number of downloads.